# Is this histogram considered bimodal?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, visualization, descriptive-statistics

Is this histogram bimodal? Because when I google what a bimodal histogram looks like, I keep getting images that say histograms like these are considered bimodal.

[image]

Isn't it unimodal because the highest peak is the only mode? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Google is wrong.  They aren't claiming that this is true: they just dug up some meta-information to be sort-of close to what you are asking for.

Comment: @Alex I edited the picture, it has a bimodal label. Why is it considered bimodal?

Comment: It's considered bimodal because it's a sum of two unimodal distributions. In Figure A you can see that if you add up a unimodal distribution with mean ~55 and a unimodal distribution with mean ~75, you'll arrive at the figure. It doesn't matter that these unimodal distributions have different values for their peaks; in fact, it's highly unlikely that you'll ever get a bimodal distribution where both peak values are equal. In this sense, the term "bimodal" is more of qualitative word - I like to think of it as saying the distribution has two *relative* maxima; the mode is the absolute maximum.

Comment: @TheDouble-JointedPrince What's that second image type called, the ones with the symmetric flower-like red patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read "mode" literally then there is just one mode: the highest bar. But that's not what "bimodal" means. Your distribution is properly labelled bimodal since it has two distinct *local* modes, with a drop between them.

Here's an example that's close to a sum of two normal distributions (Hodgkin lymphoma diagnosis as a function of age).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is bimodal because it's a sort-of sum of two normal distributions.  This can occur, for instance, if there are two sub-populations, say the one on the left is males and the one on the right is females.  Then each of males and females is distributed normally, but when you combine them together, you get a composition of two normal distributions, hence "bimodal", instead of a single normal distribution.

Note that this definition is different from what is given in first-year statistics.  For first-year statistics, "bimodal" is the opposite of "unimodal", whereas for the definition I explained, "bimodal" is the opposite of "normal".